# Cannot save a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I cannot save a rails model, it shows me "ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved".Thanks in aadvance.

```
m = Mentor.last

m.save
=> false

m.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved

m.valid?
=> true

m.errors.any?
=> false
```

Error trace is:

```
 from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:104:in `save!'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
    from (irb):120
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/charizard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Paste your error trace.

Comment: also your Mentor class

Comment: added the error trace.

Comment: Do you have any field on your `mentors` table that has constraint like `NOT NULL` but you don't validate it on your model? Or may be your constraint got added later after the record has been created?

Comment: If that is the case, then I should get a MySQL error while saving right?

Comment: No, `ActiveRecord` wrap your query in a transaction. If the transaction return false then it just rollback. I think it will show error only when you have malformed SQL statement. Either, check your schema. May be there are records on your database that is persisted in invalidate state.

That's what `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` is anyway. Your record is invalid. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotSaved.html

Comment: @phoet: At first I thought the problem is in the staging, now it appears to be in my local too. So changed the question. Sorry for not editing the same question.

Comment: @Charizard_, did you make any changes in the schema of the table like uniqueness added in a column, but the same validation is not present in the model? I guess that's what is trying to imply.

Comment: @HarshGupta: email validation is in the schema and also in the model. All other validations are only in the model. And also I am not changing a single attribute, I am just fetching from the DB and saving it back as it is.

Comment: Can you post your model and if possible, post table schema too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out this guys. I was using a MentorObserver for a before_save callback which returned false.

**If any callback returns false the save will not continue further and will raise "ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved" Exception.**

I found this by using the git bisect tool. An awesome tool.

Comment: Observers! Hmm, didn't come to mind at all. Thank you for posting your answer.